# Extracting a ContainerVisual from a UIElement

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

[ElementCompositionPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview?view=winrt-19041) class allows for extracting the backing [Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual?view=winrt-19041) from a [UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement?view=winrt-19041) via [GetElementVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.getelementvisual?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Hosting_ElementCompositionPreview_GetElementVisual_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_) API. Is there a way to extract a [ContainerVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.containervisual?view=winrt-19041) from a `UIElement`? Since a `Visual` is just the base class for all types of `Visual`s, is there a way to determine what kind of `Visual` this *extracted* `Visual` is? I tried resorting to `dynamic_cast` but that yields a `nullptr` on trying to cast it to a `ContainerVisual`. Does that indicate that this is just a plain `Visual` class instance that can't be used as anything else and restricts usage to only the `Visual` interface?

Edit:

To add more context to how I'm going about this. Here's what I have in my code

```
FrameworkElement^ elem = new UserControl();
auto visual = ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(elem);
if(auto container = dynamic_cast<ContainerVisual^>(visual)) {
  //Use ContainerVisual APIs and use it's children property to insert visuals in the visual tree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `ContainerVisual` from a `Compositor` instance which is extracted from a `UIElement`.

Please check the following code:

```
FrameworkElement^ elem =ref new UserControl();
auto _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(elem)->Compositor;
auto containerVisual= _compositor->CreateContainerVisual();
if (containerVisual)
{
    //Test if the containerVisual is a null value
    containerVisual->Comment = "1122";
}
auto str = containerVisual->Comment;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I had already tried something similar but that had led me to an exception. I guess that's a different problem and I have created a separate question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456248/cant-create-a-compositiontarget-in-uwp). Hence I posed this question to know if there's a way I can directly extract a `ContainerVisual` from the `UIElement` itself which could _possibly_ (?) avoid attaching to a `CompositionTarget`'s root.