# Can't create a CompositionTarget in UWP

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I was using the [CreateTargetForCurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor.createtargetforcurrentview?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_Compositor_CreateTargetForCurrentView) API by invoking it on a [UIElement's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement?view=winrt-19041) [Compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor?view=winrt-19041) object extracted via

```
auto visual = ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(elem);
auto compositor = visual->Compositor;
```

After this, since I want to create a tree of [Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual?view=winrt-19041)s with a sense of ordering amongst them so that I can position the visual one above the other as per my use case, I created a [ContainerVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.containervisual?view=winrt-19041) to host this tree of visuals.

```
auto containerVisual = compositor->CreateContainerVisual();
```

Now since this `ContainerVisual` needs to be attached to the `root` of a CompositionTarget, I did so (taking the reference from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CompositionVisual/cpp/VisualProperties.cpp#L233)):

```
auto compositionTarget = compositor->CreateTargetForCurrentView();
```

but this leads to a `DCOMPOSITION_ERROR_WINDOW_ALREADY_COMPOSED` which as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-error-codes) implies:

> The IDCompositionDevice::CreateTargetForHwnd method was called with
> hwnd and topmost parameters for which a visual tree already exists.

If I understand correctly, this means [IDCompositionDevice::CreateTargetForHwnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcomp/nf-dcomp-idcompositiondevice-createtargetforhwnd) has been called somehow during the lifecycle of my UWP app. This API is a `Win32` API that isn't being used directly in the app. Now my question is, in a UWP app, what API under `Windows.UI.Composition` namespace or any other, under the `C++/Cx` projection, should I be looking for that might be internally invoking `IDCompositionDevice::CreateTargetForHwnd` that's leading to this exception? Or better still, is there any API that can be used to extract a `CompositionTarget` from a `View` or `Window`? I see that there was a property `CompositionRootVisual` in the `CoreApplicationView` class that could be used to attach the `ContainerVisual` directly but it was removed in one of the API updates as per [this](https://pastebin.com/EeCgjRYe).

```
| public class Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplicationView {
-   public Visual CompositionRootVisual { get; set; }
| }
```

Strangely even the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.containervisual?view=winrt-19041#examples) refer to this route of attaching a `ContainerVisual` to a `View` but the documentation is apparently outdated.

Comment: `CompositionTarget` class represents the window on which to display the composition tree. If you want to create a visual tree by using a `CompositionTarget` instance, you may need to delete `App` files and `MainPage` files. Because `App` files and `MainPage` files has created a visual tree with XAML.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Is there any way to extract an existing composition target? I'm not sure if removing the entire XAML tree is feasible.

Comment: I couldn’t find a way to extract an existing CompositionTarget instance from a UIElement. The only way I could find is to use Compositor.CreateTargetForCurrentView method to get a  CompositionTarget instance just as you mentioned. I have tried the way removing App files and MainPage files, it could work. You could view that there is no App files and MainPage files in the official [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CompositionVisual).

Comment: If you don’t need XAML, I still suggest you  to try to remove App files and MainPage files just like the official sample.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Removing all XAML would indeed be a big task for me. Would you be aware of how to achieve something similar to `ContainerVisual` with XAML? I'm exploring the removal of XAML from my codebase.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I evaluated the removal of XAML but there's a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/visual-layer-in-desktop-apps#limitations). The Visual Layer does not have a primitive for rendering text for which a `UIElement` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interop between XAML and the Visual Layer, we shouldn’t be entangled in `CompositionTarget`. Let’s back to how to use `ContainerVisual` to create a visual tree.
Refer to the [document](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/08/26/interop-between-xaml-and-the-visual-layer/), we could use `ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(UIElement)` method to grab the backing visual for any page element, and use [ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(UIElement, Visual)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.setelementchildvisual?view=winrt-19041) method to take a created visual to a UIElement’s visual tree. There are some code in the above document and this document [Using the Visual Layer with XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/using-the-visual-layer-with-xaml), showing how to grab a visual from a `UIElement` and set a visual to a `UIElement`.

Here is the sample code you could refer to:

Add the namespaces and a header:

```
#include "windowsnumerics.h"

using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
```

Declare some members:

```
private:
    Compositor^ _compositor;
    ContainerVisual^ _root;
    Visual^ CreateChildElement();
```

The code to grab a visual and set a visual:

```
void App2::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(this)->Compositor;
    _root = _compositor->CreateContainerVisual();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        _root->Children->InsertAtTop(CreateChildElement());
    }
    ElementCompositionPreview::SetElementChildVisual(this, _root);

}

Visual^ App2::MainPage::CreateChildElement()
{
    auto element = _compositor->CreateContainerVisual();
    element->Size = float2(100.0f, 100.0f);

    //
    // Position this visual randomly within our window
    //
    element->Offset = float3(((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 400, ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 400, 0.0f);

    //
    // The outer rectangle is always white
    //
    auto visual = _compositor->CreateSpriteVisual();
    element->Children->InsertAtTop(visual);
    visual->Brush = _compositor->CreateColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x11, 0xFF));
    visual->Size = float2(100.0f, 100.0f);

    //
    // The inner rectangle is inset from the outer by three pixels all around
    //
    auto child = _compositor->CreateSpriteVisual();
    visual->Children->InsertAtTop(child);
    child->Offset = float3(3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
    child->Size = float2(94.0f, 94.0f);

    //
    // Pick a random color for every rectangle
    //
    byte red = (byte)(0xFF * (0.2f + (((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) / 0.8f)));
    byte green = (byte)(0xFF * (0.2f + (((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) / 0.8f)));
    byte blue = (byte)(0xFF * (0.2f + (((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) / 0.8f)));
    child->Brush = _compositor->CreateColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(0xFF, red, green, blue));

    //
    // Make the subtree root visual partially transparent. This will cause each visual in the subtree
    // to render partially transparent, since a visual's opacity is multiplied with its parent's
    // opacity
    //
    element->Opacity = 0.8f;

    return element;

}
```